# captcha not working with varnish

Tags: php, caching, captcha, varnish

I stumbled upon this strange issue. Since I installed/enabled Varnish cache on the server php captcha always gives error for wrong code entry so captcha doesn't work at all. It does display code image but when code is entered it returns error.

Interestingly when I disable Varnish then captcha will work smoothly. Any idea, what is causing this issue?

Comment: Make sure you send the no-cache headers with your captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your captcha page that generates a captcha code is cached leading to it giving the user the same captcha each time. Make that page uncacheable by sending proper no-cache/0 ttl headers.